# Flash External Preloader or Self Preloader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, preloader

I've this Flash Professional Project that I'm building inside Flash Builder. It's a single swf file to be exported.

Will self preloaded work for this SWF file, because I think the preloader (progress bar) will not show because flash exports everything in the first frame because of all movie clips set as export to frame 1, and I need those as well since I'm instantiating them in my Document Class.

Should I go for an external SWF preloader strategy or is there a safe way to do self preloader?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Flash Builder. In Flash proper you can turn off the "export in first frame" thing. You could also create a new Frame 1 with the preloader (again, in Flash) and have the SWF start executing when the preloader moves the playhead to Frame 2.

Answer (score 0):

Their are two ways :

1) choose some of the very heavy movieclips ( say those consisting of bitmaps or lots of animations). Turn off the "export in first frame" for them. And place those movieclips on the 2nd frame. Follow the process for all the "heavy movieclips", unless you make sure that the preloader shows up while testing it live.

2) Yes, the other method as you said is quite better, is to use another swf for preloader. But before using this method, make sure that their is no restriction on using more than 1 swf for your project.

V.

Answer (score 0):

When working with flash builder you have nothing to worry about because adobe already did everything for you.

Just use the build in [Flash builder preloader](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-custom-preloader.html)